Tkinter input taken after enter key pressed
I'm new to tkinter as I usually work in C. I wrote a simple code in tkinter, and I'd like to make it so on this snippet the input is stored in the variable name after the enter key is pressed, and that the input box disapears (probably using destroy.()).
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title = 'Shit game v1.0'
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')

label = tk.Label(text = "Name?: " ,foreground = "green", background = "black")
entry = tk.Entry(root, fg="green", bg="black", width=50)
label.pack()
entry.pack()

#name = entry.get()


# place a label on the root window
message = tk.Label(root, text=
 "What is your name?",
foreground = "green",
background = "black",
width = 1000,
height = 1000)

message.pack()

if entry == True:
    name = entry.get()
    message2 = tk.Label(root, text=
    f"Welcome {name}! Let's begin!",
    foreground = "green",
    background = "black",
    width = 1000,
    height = 1000)

    message2.pack()





root.mainloop()

I tried:
def get_name(event):
    name = entry.get()
if entry == True:
    name = entry.get()
    message2 = tk.Label(root, text=
    f"Welcome {name}! Let's begin!",
    foreground = "green",
    background = "black",
    width = 1000,
    height = 1000)

    message2.pack()

entry.bind('<Return>', get_name)



you need to fix the missing closing quotes from your code

You can accomplish this with a pretty minimal setup like so (note that I've removed some of the styling to keep things simpler)
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title = 'Shit game v1.0'
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')

msg_label = tk.Label(root, text='What is your name?')  # create a label
msg_label.pack()  # add the label to the UI

name_entry = tk.Entry(root)  # create an Entry to accept user input
name_entry.bind(  # bind the enter key shortcut
    '<Return>',
    lambda _: [  # you can call a sequence of functions w/ a lambda like this...
        # update the label's text
        msg_label.config(text=f"Welcome {name_entry.get()}, let's begin!"),
        # remove the Entry widget
        name_entry.pack_forget()
    ]
)
name_entry.pack()  # add the Entry to the UI

root.mainloop()

As Bryan Oakley has pointed out, it's usually better practice to define functions for more complex tasks, rather than adding a bunch of things to a single lambda, so here's how to accomplish this using that approach:
import tkinter as tk


def accept_name() -> None:
    """
    Collect the user's name, update the message label, 
    and hide the name entry widget
    """
    # update the label's text
    msg_label.config(text=f"Welcome {name_entry.get()}, let's begin!"),
    # remove the Entry widget
    name_entry.pack_forget()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title = 'Shit game v1.0'
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')

msg_label = tk.Label(root, text='What is your name?')  # create a label
msg_label.pack()  # add the label to the UI

name_entry = tk.Entry(root)  # create an Entry to accept user input
# bind the enter key shortcut
name_entry.bind('<Return>', lambda _: accept_name())
name_entry.pack()  # add the Entry to the UI

root.mainloop()

Also, it's worth noting that the lambda now only serves to absorb the event parameter generated by the binding to '<Return>' (represented by the underscore _). You can do this instead:
name_entry.bind('<Return>', accept_name)

...if you update the definition of accept_name to accept the incoming argument (even if you aren't going to use it)
def accept_name(_event=None) -> None: ...


Personally I think cramming so much code in a lambda is an antipattern. I think a proper function would make this code easier to understand, maintain, and debug.

@BryanOakley that's probably fair! I just figured that this wasn't too over the top for a lambda, but I tend to agree. I'll add an example of using a dedicated function to this answer as well.

Thank you both for the excellent answers!
